# Strange JPQL issue: adding less restrictive query parameters returns less rows

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

We've got an entity model like this (non-related fields omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    //The other portion of the sum that is invoiced from another payer.
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentInvoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Invoice otherPayersInvoice;

    //The patient's invoice, which is the parent of this other payer's invoice.
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Invoice parentInvoice;

    @ManyToOne
    private Payer payer;
}
```

So, basically we will split invoice's into parts and store the relations within the entities.

The following query works and returns all invoices by payerId:

```
SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE i.payer.id = :payerId
```

However, when i extend the query to also list all "child" invoices that the payer may have (Invoices invoiced from another payer), I get no results at all and no error or warning anywhere whatsoever.

```
SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE i.payer.id = :payerId OR
    (i.parentInvoice IS NOT NULL AND i.parentInvoice.payer.id = :payerId)
```

What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: Why not look at the SQL generated ?

Comment: Good point. Will check that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i.parentInvoice.payer.id
```

This is doing an INNER join from Invoice to its parent to its payer, which will filter all rows without a parent or payer.

You need to use an outer-join instead.

```
SELECT i FROM Invoice i join i.parentInvoice parent join p.payer parentPayer join i.payer payer WHERE payer.id = :payerId OR (parentPayer.id = :payerId)
```

Comment: Still no luck.. Getting no results. Is there something wrong with my @OneToOne annotations?